# Socket Communication Between Separate Machines

Tags: java, sockets

Take the following basic programs:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TestServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(12345);
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                try {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
                    out.println(new java.util.Date().toString());
                    out.close();
                } finally {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }
}


public class TestClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("0.0.0.0",12345); // Stack trace points to this line as the one with the error
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println(in.readLine());
            in.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The `TestServer` program waits for a client to connect to it so that it can send information, which is, in this case, the current date, to the client. At my home computer in my IDE (JCreator, by the way), I can run both the `TestServer` program and the `TestClient` program on the same computer and get the desired result. The problem is that when I run the `TestClient` program on a *different* computer and attempt to connect to the `TestServer` program, I keep getting the message `IOException: Connection refused`.

Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: it is not clear from your question that you changed the ip address from "0.0.0.0" to that of the remote machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to connect to the server with a wrong IP address (**0.0.0.0**).

You'll need to know the IP address of the computer running the server program and use that to instantiate the socket in your client program.

Note that the server should be reachable from the client computer.

Comment: So each computer has its own IP address?

Comment: Then why does the `getInetAddress()` method of the `ServerSocket` class return `0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0`?